# Millisec convert to date can't show at emulator

Tags: flutter

I try to convert `int ts=1646274840000` to a date. When I start to debug this code can read and at variable it success show the output but at emulator, the output does not show the date. Someone can help me?

My code

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import 'api_service.dart';

class AppointmentList extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? token;
  AppointmentList({
    Key? key,
    this.token
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppointmentListState createState() => _AppointmentListState();
}

class _AppointmentListState extends State<AppointmentList> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    APIService.getAppointmentList(widget.token!);
    
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Appointment Listing"),
      ),
      //body: _appointmentListUI(),
      body: _time(),
    );
  }
}
  _time() {
    
    int ts=1646274840000; 
    DateTime tsdate = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(ts);
String fdatetime = DateFormat('dd-MMM-yyy').format(tsdate);
if (kDebugMode) {
  print(fdatetime);
} 
  
  }
```

The variable show, the date but at emulator does not show the date

[image: At the variable show the date but at emulator does not show the date]

Comment: Your `_time` method *prints* the date (which would be observable from the debug console), but it doesn't return a *widget* for the Flutter application (specifically `Scaffold`) to show.  In fact, your `_time` method doesn't explicitly return anything at all (and therefore implicitly returns `null`) to its caller.  You probably want `_time` to do something like `return Text(fdatetime);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
_time() {
            
    int ts=1646274840000; 
    DateTime tsdate = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(ts);
    String fdatetime = DateFormat('dd-MMM-yyy').format(tsdate);
    return Container(
        child: Text(fdatetime),);
   
}
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.